# Загрузка изображений в профиль с помощью VK Android SDK

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как загрузить изображение в альбом или на стену пользователя?
Использую [официальную документацию VK Android SDK](https://new.vk.com/dev/android_sdk)
4. Вызов методов API → 6) Загрузка фото на сервера VK

Первая проблема: при попытке использовать `getPhoto()`, я получаю ошибку

> cannot resolve method.

Куда именно писать методы, описанные в [Документации по загрузке файлов](https://new.vk.com/dev/upload_files)? В поле `onComplete` или `onResult`? Возможно мне стало бы понятней, если бы был наглядный пример.

[Ссылка на pastebin c тем, что у меня получилось](http://pastebin.com/4Ss7R8ZJ).

Ниже метод, который у меня не получается использовать:

```
final Bitmap photo = getPhoto(); 
VKRequest request = VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest(new VKUploadImage(photo,
        VKImageParameters.jpgImage(0.9f)), 0, 60479154);
```

Comment: У вас нету в коде метода `getPhoto()` о чём вам и говорит компилятор.

Comment: Я затрудняюсь его реализовать

Comment: Т.е. ваш вопрос не про VKSDK, а про получение Bitmap объекта?

Comment: Я познакомился с android vk sdk пару дней назад, и до сих пор не смог разобраться даже в том как загрузить простую фотографию. Очень много гуглил и уже совсем запутался, поэтому я уже ничего не понимаю и мне казалось, что bitmap объект и входит в VKSdk. Мой вопрос про то как загрузить фотографию в свой альбом вконтакте на  java for adnroid

Comment: Ошибся употребив слово "фотография", изображение. Необходимо взять изображение расположенное в ресурсах моей программы (в drawable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо разбить задачу на части. Вот [код](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710690/3212712) для получения bitMap объекта из пути к фото на девайсе:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
```

Из ресурсов [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035869/3212712):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       R.drawable.icon_resource);
```

Разобравшись с этим вам надо разобраться как получить путь к файлу этому после делания фото камерой. После этого - как отправлять это в ВК. Простого метода типа `makePhotoAndSendItToVKAlbumWithMagic()` не существует.

Comment: Прошу прощение меня getPhoto() сбивает с толку. Задача загрузить изображение, взяв его из ресурсов приложения, я так понимаю из drawable. Bitmap необходим, чтобы указать путь к изображению в ресурсах?

Comment: Обновил ответ...